# What should be My request Body of Gmail api which sends email?

Tags: http, curl, oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-api

I enable gmail api in console of google cloud .

Implemented the oauth2.0 got the token

Hit the gmail api for sending email ([this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)) .

In docs it has shown what should be sent in request body ([this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message)) but I can't understand it . Please help me with it . a example request body will help me understand better

I am not implementing it with google client library . I know it is the preferred way but I want to try it this way . Kindly help me . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of one of mine.  It's a Django project, but should help.

```
email = render_to_string('scheduling/emails/user_send_cancel_email.html',{'context':context})
subject = 'Your showing at' + ' ' + listing_address.line + ' has been cancelled'
toUserEmail = lead.email_address
try:

    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['To'] = toUserEmail
    message['From'] = request.user.email
    message['Subject'] = subject

    html = MIMEText(email,'html')
    message.attach(html)
    encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()

    send_message = service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body={'raw':encoded_message}).execute()
```

Comment: How do yo handle google login on your server side ? . on Django how do you handle google login . its ask me for google login and consent . I am using gmail api with client library in my flask app . I was thinking of handling oauth process till getting acces token on frontend then sending only access token to server and then call the gmail api with token via client library

Comment: I use the oath2 method, then save the credentials in a field in my user model. , Then use the refresh token everytime they need it.

Comment: can I see your code of entire application . if its ok ? . I still didn't get how you login on server as you cant put email and password .